# Secure Encrypt Decrypt Algurithm can use for Android,C#,PHP,iPhone

Tags: c#, php, android, encryption

I'm going to encrypt my data transferring  between my multi platform apps. My question is that which algorithm can be used that work for all these platforms?

That should have these parameters:

1. Dynamic key and iv.
2. Supported in C#, Android, Swift, PHP.
3. Be secure enough.

It will be welcome if anybody give me some samples or links for each platform.

**UPDATE:**

I tried these classes:

**Android:**

```
public class Cryptor {
        private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
        private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
        private Cipher cipher;

        public Cryptor(byte[] key_par,byte[] iv_par)
        {
            keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key_par, "AES");
            ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv_par);
            try {
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/ZeroPadding");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public byte[] encrypt(byte[] input) throws Exception
        {
            if(text == null || text.length() == 0)
                throw new Exception("Empty input");
            byte[] encrypted = null;
            try {
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
                encrypted = cipher.doFinal(input);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return encrypted;
        }
        public byte[] decrypt(String code) throws Exception
        {
            if(code == null || code.length() == 0)
                throw new Exception("Empty string");
            byte[] decrypted = null;
            try {
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
                decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return decrypted;
        }
        public static String bytesToHex(byte[] data)
        {
            if (data==null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            int len = data.length;
            String str = "";
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                if ((data[i]&0xFF)<16)
                    str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
                else
                    str = str + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
            }
            return str;
        }
        public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
            if (str==null) {
                return null;
            } else if (str.length() < 2) {
                return null;
            } else {
                int len = str.length() / 2;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
                for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                    buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
                }
                return buffer;
            }
        }
}
```

**PHP:**

```
class MCrypt
{
    protected $in_iv;
    protected $in_key;

    function __construct($in_key , $in_iv)
    {
        $this->key = $in_key;
        $this->iv = $in_iv;
    }

    function encrypt($str) {
        $iv = $this->iv;
        $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
        $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $str);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        return bin2hex($encrypted);
    }

    function decrypt($code) {
        $code = $this->hex2bin($code);
        $iv = $this->iv;
        $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
        $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $code);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        return utf8_encode(trim($decrypted));
    }

    protected function hex2bin($hexdata) {
        $bindata = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2) {
            $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2)));
        }
        return $bindata;
    }
}
```

**C#:**

```
class Cryptor
{
    private byte[] iv;
    private byte[] key;
    public Cypher(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.iv = iv;
    }
    public byte[] EncryptRJ128(byte[] input)
    {
        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] encrypted;
        using (var rj = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            try
            {
                rj.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                rj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                rj.KeySize = 128;
                rj.BlockSize = 128;
                rj.Key = key;
                rj.IV = iv;
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                var sr = new StreamWriter(cs);
                sr.Write(input);
                sr.Flush();
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                encrypted = ms.ToArray();
            }
            finally
            {
                rj.Clear();
            }
        }
        return encrypted;
    }

    public String DecryptRJ128(byte[] input)
    {
        var sRet = "";
        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        using (var rj = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            try
            {
                rj.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                rj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                rj.KeySize = 128;
                rj.BlockSize = 128;
                rj.Key = key;
                rj.IV = iv;
                var ms = new MemoryStream(input);
                var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                var sr = new StreamReader(cs);
                sRet = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            finally
            {
                rj.Clear();
            }
        }
        return sRet;
    }
}
```

**TEST:**

This is some example that I used to test:

```
key ={  106,104,103,97,103,94,115,106,102,96,115,53,53,52,55,53}
iv  ={104,49,52,56,114,102,103,49,48,50,52,97,56,51,118,52}
input ={57,102,117,105,65,75,113,105,108,119,113,54,109,73,89,104}
```

Now trying to encrypt:

```
Android and PHP output:
170, 29, 170, 139, 14, 192, 81, 232, 41, 237, 25, 19, 130, 237, 15, 198

c# OUTPUT:
59 , 85 , 127 , 29 , 161 , 145 , 23 , 127 , 246 , 100 , 157 , 234 , 128 , 65
```

Comment: Dear Jim, You are expected to atleast code a little.. give it a try and then ask question here.. SO doesn't write codes... It simply helps developers in their problems..

Comment: I've wrote so many codes and tries. Each time someone said me you're wrong in somewhere. I asked this question to know which exact algorithm and parameters is the best and available in all platforms, to start codding more powerful.

Comment: Mention some of them.. And provide us with some code to test upon..

Comment: OK, I'll update my post in some minutes.

Comment: https://github.com/RNCryptor supports  all those languages and is pretty secure

Comment: The code looks compatible. I get a different output with your example values. Please don't use integer arrays. You should use hex-encoded strings for all of those example values.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I used string value too but no difference ! Also these values are byte arrays not raw integers

Comment: Yes, but byte arrays defined through a list of *integers* might be different in Java and C#, because they have different domains. I don't remember which is which, but one has signed values and the other unsigned. That's why it is better to always use a common format for this like hex.